# How to make /category/ URL load properly instead of 404 error?

Tags: categories, theme-development, taxonomy

I have seen the problem before when hacking in WordPress

When trying to access the

**www.example.com/category/**

I get a 404-page displayed.

Is there a way to display something useful such as a page with custom code instead of the 404-page?

Need your help to figure this out, please tell me if something is unclear.
I tried to add the tags category-base and category-page but that did not work. I you have suggestions on good tags please inform me.
Thanks
Anthony

Comment: Are you using the base theme or have you developed your own?

Comment: is the 404 page is your generic hosting age or one that looks like it is generated by wordpress?

Comment: I am making a child theme of twentythirteen. But the code I have been testing on is the 2013 theme files. The 404 i generated by wordpress.
My setup environment is on my local machine, using UniServer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is such way. To be precise, there are many ways to accomplish that.

You can **add 'Category' page**. Make sure that its slug is set to 'category'. If you go to example.com/category/ then this page will be shown. If there were no custom changes to rewrite rules, then WordPress will first try to match pages, and then categories, so it should work.

You can also **remove category base from url**. You can do this using some plugins ([WP No Category Base - WPML compatible](http://wordpress.org/plugins/no-category-base-wpml/) is one of plugins you could use).

Comment: Thanks! The first option did work, could there be any issues with creating a page with the category slug?

Comment: No category base plugin makes category pages in non default language to return 404 error.